# Formal Proof Problem

Tags: formal-proofs

I'm doing this formal proof problem with 10 steps, given these three premises;

1) (G V H) ⊃ I

2) (J V K) ⊃ ~I

3) K / ∴ ~H

4 - 10 is unknown. I tried using material implication and DeMorgan's Theorem on that step, but failed. Any help would be appreciated!